# PasteSpecial causing a bug

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the content of a series of cells from C:AH down onto the line below.

This sub is nested in another that will loop and enter another line below all of this.

I have got the following so far

```
Sub RowDiv1()

Dim Leg1 As Range
Dim Leg2 As Range
Dim Leg3 As Range
Dim Leg4 As Range
Dim Leg5 As Range
Dim Leg6 As Range
Dim Leg7 As Range
Dim Leg8 As Range

Dim C1 As Range

With Worksheets("Working Sheet 1")
    Set Leg1 = .Range(.Range("C6000").End(xlUp), .Range("AH6000").End(xlUp))
    With Leg1
        .Cut
    End With

Set C1 = .Range("C6000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, -2)
    With C1
        'This is the paste line that is causing a problem
        .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

As you can see, this is the cut for the first of the 8 legs.
I was planning on repeating this code to cut up the same line 8 times.

This is an example of one line of my code

```
18-Apr-17|  11:00:30|   Walker1_Leg1|   319437.222| 146279.951| -32.768|    Walker1_Leg2|   319417.07|  146268.105| -32.768|    Walker1_Leg3|   319410.548| 146268.368| -32.768|    Walker1_Leg4|   319398.806| 146288.339| -32.768|    Walker1_Leg5|   319399.702| 146297.706| -32.768|    Walker1_Leg6|   319419.94|  146309.425| -32.768|    Walker1_Leg7|   319428.284| 146305.858| -2.533| Walker1_Leg8|   319440.055| 146285.716| -32.768
```

How can I fix this problem?

Cheers

James

Comment: You cannot pastespecial with cut cells.  You will need to copy/pastespecial then clear the contents of the former range.

Comment: try inserting a row to move it down one row instead ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it as,

```
Sub RowDiv1()
    With Worksheets("Working Sheet 1")
        With .Range(.Range("C6000").End(xlUp), .Range("AH6000").End(xlUp))
            .Cells(1).Offset(1, -2).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrays to make it a little quicker:

```
Sub RowDiv1()

Dim rng As Range
Dim iArr() As Variant
Dim oarr() As Variant
Dim i&, j&
ReDim oarr(1 To 8, 1 To 4) As Variant
With Worksheets("Working Sheet 1")
    Set rng = .Range(.Range("C6000").End(xlUp), .Range("AH6000").End(xlUp))
    iArr = rng.Value
    j = 1
    For i = LBound(iArr, 2) To UBound(iArr, 2) Step 4
        oarr(j, 1) = iArr(1, i)
        oarr(j, 2) = iArr(1, i + 1)
        oarr(j, 3) = iArr(1, i + 2)
        oarr(j, 4) = iArr(1, i + 3)
        j = j + 1
    Next i
    .Range("A6000").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(8, 4).Value = oarr
    rng.ClearContents

End With
```